# Overflow: Hidden Deleting scrolling script HRML

Tags: html, css

Whenever I Try to use

```css
div {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

scrolling using mouse doesn't work anymore, all I can do to scroll is using Buttons or  tags

I tried to make scrolling possible without scroll at the right side of website because it makes everything ugly, for every help I'm very thankful

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide scroll bar, but while still being able to scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-while-still-being-able-to-scroll)

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved And fixed
for people encountering this problem theres the solution:

```css
html {
   overflow: scroll;
   overflow-x: hidden;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #FF0000;
}
```

It worked for me perfectly